# Using FormsAuthentication in asp.net to redirect on unprotected page

Tags: asp.net, redirect, forms-authentication

I have a weird scenario. I have `forms authentication` working properly. My protected pages are in a folder and if I navigate to them I get redirected to the login page with a return `URL` in the `querystring`. So far so good. BUT I have one page that is a search results page. The requirement is that the page hide some of it's data if the user is not logged in, but the rest of the page is viewable as normal.

I did some trickery to hide panels with the authenticated only data, works fine. The issue I have is that if the user goes through the search process (which is multi-step) and after seeing the results wants to log in, they would have to click a login link at the top of the page. This will load the login page WITHOUT a return url. After all, the user clicked a link to a new page (the login page). After submitting the login info, the referrer is now wrong (it would be the current login page).

So without messing up the `FormsAuthentication` system that works so well for protected folders, how can I return a user to the last place they were after they choose to login on their own (from a non-protected page). I realize that this is not a flaw in FormsAuthentication and the solution might not have anything to do with that at all, just wanted some options. Any suggestions?

Comment: Jeff, if I understand you right, the user came from a search page and you want to re-direct them to the search page? and your complication is that a search parameter doesn't conveniently go into query string?

Comment: @DaveA,  i think he is using UriRefferer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

Comment: @Devjosh, I was thinking that. But, while I've done more MVC than web-forms, I noticed the referer doesn't work well with pages that were posted to (like search result pages)

Comment: Sorry you guys, I asked a question and then disappeared because I got side tracked on other issues for a while. I apologize!! In a nutshell, I have a page that is NOT in a protected folder, but it does have a login link at the top of the page. You only get the Url to return to when you try to navigate to a page in a protected folder.

Comment: I actually solved the issue, but I am not sure it's the best solution. I created a base page that inherits Page. Then all of my pages inherit myBasePage. myBasePage contains a string that holds the Url of that page. login.aspx does inherit, but does not store it's own url. So any page I go to updates the myBasePage.MyUrl. Then inside the login.aspx.cs after submit I redirect to the myBasePage.MyUrl. It works, but it's kind of a hack. Any better suggestions than that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

It will give you the previous page url.

### Edit 1

Here is a similar question on `SO`

[Finding previous page Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772780/finding-previous-page-url)

### Edit 2

```
public Page PreviousPage { get; }
```

Here is msdn link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: This actually will not work because say you are on page1.aspx. Then you click a login button which brings you to login.aspx. You fill out the form and click submit. On the postback the UrlReferrer would be login.aspx because that is the last page you were on before the postback.