# How to get the original URL after a HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url-rewriting

Posted this question yesterday, but was a bit confusing, so I've deleted and posted again!

Well, I call (for example) a server with this link (I call it "original url") :

```
http://example.com/page/?IDL=1&IDH=90
```

Now, on this server, I do a sort of url rewriting, changing the requested url in :

```
http://example.com/myhandler404/page:PORT/?ID=34&IDL=1&IDH=90
```

and than, trough `HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute()`, I call this new URL.

Now, is it possible, (i'm `http://example.com/myhandler404/page:PORT/?ID=34&IDL=1&IDH=90`) get the "original url" of the request? Without parsing/replacing, maybe accessing to some Execute object's properties?

Tried with `Request.UrlReferrer` but I get a null object?!?!?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Server.Transfer` instead of `Execute`, together with [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Or attach the original URL to the QueryString

http://www.myserver.it/myhandler404/page:PORT/?ID=34&IDL=1&IDH=90**&OriginalUrl=http://www.myserver.it/page/?IDL=1&IDH=90**

And read it as you do for ID, IDL and IDH.

Comment: I can't edit that code unfortunatly! I believe there are the object/properties also with Execute to get the "OriginalUrl"...

Comment: As I said, I can't edit the code near the Execute zone. So I can't edit the Execute function. Reading to this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587510/how-to-detect-if-an-aspx-page-was-called-from-server-execute @stevemegson answer "Server.Execute runs the new page with the same context as the original page, all the properties of Request should still reflect the original request to Webpage.aspx" but I don't find which parameter I should call...

Comment: Ok, I thought the URL was somehow generated independently from the Execute code. Just checked `Request.Url` and in my test it contains the original URL?

Answer (score 0):

Use RawUrl. 
It's always unchanged while one or several Server.Transfer(s):

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl
```